# Control Time and Send Query Every Second with Node Js?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, ajax

I am writing a web software with node js. I am also using Mssql database. I have a table that has a datetime value and a bit value. The bit value is always 0 until the real time is equals the value that datetime has. If they equals, the bit value will be 1.

Okey the question is "How can I check the realtime and the datetime value in the table, everytime?"

I used setInterval func and the server closed itself after 3 or 4 time. Weird thing is I can't see any error code or anything like that after the server closed.

I need help. If you have any idea about how to solve, please help me. I heard something about socket.io but I don't now how to adapt it.

Comment: " until the real time is equals the value "  Hitting an exact datetime may be problematic.   Perhaps >=

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying a database every second is probably too frequent. It's possible one query won't finish before the next one starts.

To work around this you should use a new database connection each time your setInterval handler runs.  That way your new query still has a chance of working if the previous query is not done. Getting a new database connection each time is reasonable if you use a  [*connection pool*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connection-pools) in your program, and request your new connections from that pool.

Something like this: not debugged.

```
const sql = require('mssql')

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
const poolConnect = pool.connect()

pool.on('error', err => {
    // ... error handler
})

function intervalTimer() {
    return poolConnect.then((pool) => {
            pool
              .request()
              .execute('SELECT whatever', (err, result) => {
                // ... error checks
                console.dir(result)
            })
         }).catch(err => {
            // ... error handler
         })
}
```

Or, you can even skip the query if the previous one isn't done. This code does that with an `intervalTimerInProgress` boolean value. It sets it right before starting the query, and clears it when the query finishes.

```
const sql = require('mssql')

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
const poolConnect = pool.connect()

pool.on('error', err => {
    // ... error handler
})

let intervalTimerInProgress = false
function intervalTimer() {
  if (!intervalTimerInProgress) {
    intervalTimerInProgress = true
    return poolConnect.then((pool) => {
            pool
              .request()
              .execute('SELECT whatever', (err, result) => {
                // ... error checks
                console.dir(result)
                intervalTimerInProgress = false
            })
         }).catch(err => {
            // ... error handler
         })
  }
}
```

Again, polling a DBMS once a second is a design choice you should reconsider. DBMSs are the scarcest resource and the bottleneck in many web apps, and polling them can put bigger loads on them than you want.